# kohana 3 convert returned object into select options

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

Having hard time figuring out how to take the returned orm object and converting it to a usable array for the helper FORM::select

```
$this->template->content = View::factory('form')
->bind('errors', $errors)
->bind('categories', $categories);


$categories = ORM::factory('category');

$categories->order_by('category');

$categories = $categories->find_all();
```

In the form view I have

```
<tr>
<td><?php echo Form::label('category', 'Category'); ?></td>
<td><?php echo Form::select('category', $categories, $category); ?></td>
</tr>
```

How do I convert the returned object array $categories into an attributes array $categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[as_array()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/ORM#as_array) is there to do the trick for you. Just use this line.

```
$categories = $categories->find_all()->as_array('id', 'category_label');
```

Comment: SUPER! I love this site. Thank you